# FabricJS - mouse:move target is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

:)

I'm actually migrating a FabricJS module from Angular to ReactJS, and I have the following problem.

I have a mouse move handler to show divs depending on the FabricJS object I'm hovering.

In my class, I have this initializer:

```
initHandlers: function () {
    var mouseMovePlacing = this.mouseMovePlacing.bind(this);
    this.template.canvas.on("mouse:move", mouseMovePlacing);
}
```

And it's calling this function:

```
mouseMovePlacing: function (event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

By reading FabricJS docs, I found that event is supposed to be an object with an attribute named target, which contains an attribute named type, which is the name of our Fabric object.
The problem is that when I'm hovering an object on my Canvas, target is always null.

Do you guys have suggestions ?

Comment: maybe a little fiddle could help

Comment: I'd like to, but I can't reproduce the bug :/

Comment: If you can't reproduce the bug it is not a bug ;) all the best

Comment: please add an object to canvas and post the canvas.getObjects() dump and the dump of the object that arrive in the handler when you are hovering the fabric object

Comment: [Here is the canvas.getObjects()](http://pastebin.com/iCDMK5fx)
What is _the dump of the object that arrive in the handler when you are hovering the fabric object_ ?